# Is Anti malware available with any version of windows 7 embedded, Or please suggest any 3rd party anti malware for windows7 embedded

Tags: windows-7-embedded

Is Anti malware available with any version of windows 7 embedded, or please suggest any 3rd party anti malware for windows7 embedded.
If available then let me know how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Given the nature of the systems, we went past typical Windows anti-malware software and used VMWare's Carbon Black. Once the system was configured, it was essentially locked down from all changes.